# Jmxtrans monitors solr issue

Tags: solr, jmxtrans

I want to monitor solr, and have the jmxtrans config:

```
{
   "servers":[
      {
         "port":"8099",
         "host":"localhost",
         "queries":[
            {
               "obj":"solr/*:type=/select,id=org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler",
               "resultAlias":"solr",
               "attr":[
                    "requests","errors","avgRequestsPerSecond","avgTimePerRequest","95thPcRequestTime"
               ],

               "outputWriters":[
                  {
                     "@class":"com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.KeyOutWriter",
                     "settings":{
                        "outputFile" : "/tmp/jmx.log",
                        "maxLogFileSize" : "10MB",
                        "maxLogBackupFiles" : 2,
                        "debug" : true
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have configure the wildcard domain name

```
"obj":"solr/*:type=/select,id=org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler"
```

but I get the following result without domain name:

```
localhost_8099.solr.errors 0   1446715240625
localhost_8099.solr.avgRequestsPerSecond   0.00883917964270778 1446715240625
localhost_8099.solr.avgTimePerRequest  1.99831994970047    1446715240625
localhost_8099.solr.95thPcRequestTime  3.8249146499999997  1446715240625
localhost_8099.solr.requests   717419  1446715241205
localhost_8099.solr.errors 0   1446715241205
```

I tried typeNames: https://code.google.com/p/jmxtrans/wiki/Queries
But it seems doesn't support domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, add the following configuration:

```
...
    "obj":"solr/*:type=/select,id=org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler",
    "useObjDomainAsKey":true,
...
```